# How to get tabulate to expand vertically to fit larger text in ConTeXt?

Tags: tables, context

I used the following text to create a tabulate environment:

```
\definefont[bigfont][name:alegreyasansscextrabold at 50pt]

\define[1]\maketextbig{{\bigfont #1}}

\starttext

    \starttabulate[|p|p|p|]
        \HL
        \NC A \NC B \NC C \NC\NR
        \HL
        \NC \maketextbig{big text} \NC regular text \NC regular text \NC\NR
        \NC \maketextbig{big text} \NC regular text \NC regular text \NC\NR
        \NC \maketextbig{big text} \NC regular text \NC regular text \NC\NR
        \NC \maketextbig{big text} \NC regular text \NC regular text \NC\NR
        \HL
    \stoptabulate


\stoptext
```

When compiled, the big text smashes together. How can I get the rows to expand, and let the other text in the rows be centered vertically?

Comment: `alegreyasansscextrabold` is not recognized when I compile your MWE. I had to switch to `pagella` (I have a lmtx install, not texlive). 
Btw, I understand you want an answer with `tabulate`? Wouldn't it be easier to achieve with `xtable`?

Comment: It doesn't matter to me which table to use, I just want so long as the table has the ability to split across pages, showing the first row on each page, and vertical centering. of the text on the rows. I've always been so confused which table to use in ConTeXt there are so many ways, I don't know which is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think extreme tables are a convenient way to answer your problem. They split nicely accross pages, as requested in your comment.The stretch option is described in extreme tabulars manual. It can be used to make the table use the whole horizontal space.

```
\definefont[bigfont][name:pagella at 50pt]

\define[1]\maketextbig{{\bigfont #1}}

\starttext

\startxtable [align={middle,lohi},option=stretch]
   \startxrow 
      \startxcell A
      \stopxcell
      \startxcell B
      \stopxcell
      \startxcell C
      \stopxcell
   \stopxrow
   \startxrow 
      \startxcell \maketextbig{big text}
      \stopxcell
      \startxcell regular text
      \stopxcell
      \startxcell regular text
      \stopxcell
   \stopxrow
   \startxrow 
      \startxcell \maketextbig{big text}
      \stopxcell
      \startxcell regular text
      \stopxcell
      \startxcell regular text
      \stopxcell
   \stopxrow
   \startxrow 
      \startxcell \maketextbig{big text}
      \stopxcell
      \startxcell regular text
      \stopxcell
      \startxcell regular text
      \stopxcell
   \stopxrow
\stopxtable

\stoptext
```

[image: compilation output]